# How to use Shared Preferences in adapter?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView studentName, studentMatrik, studentPhone, studentAddress, studentStatus, studentMail, studentCon, studentId;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    Button buttonMap;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checked", false);
    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        studentMatrik = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMatrik);
        studentPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentPhone);
        studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
        studentStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentStatus);
        studentMail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMail);
        studentCon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentCon);
        studentId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentId);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        buttonMap = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
        buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Latitude",studentMail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude",studentCon.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Address",studentAddress.getText().toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
                    editor.commit();
                    String id = studentId.getText().toString();
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student");
                    String name = "Check";
                    databaseReference.child(id).child("stat").setValue(name);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    String id = studentId.getText().toString();
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student");
                    String name = "Not Check";
                    databaseReference.child(id).child("stat").setValue(name);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I use shared preference to save the checkbox value in adapter? I've try doing it though but still wrong... If I have checked the checkbox, I want the checkbox still be checked when I quit and open back the app, and it will do the same when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: you have to make hashmap which stores checkbox value and id which helps in add or delete and save it to the shared preference if you want

Comment: First, you need to know how to store/read the value on sharedPreference. This will help to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/5167909

Answer (score 0):

Does setting

```
checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Not make it work as you want?

Answer (score 0):

On Check event save the boolean data to `SharedPreferences` with the **id of the list item as key**. Then add some code to `ViewHolder` to check in `SharedPreference` if an item should be checked before displaying it. This way, the `ViewHolder` can check if a `CheckBox` has checked value in `SharedPreference` every time it is displayed